# Нужна ли запятая в моем следующем предложении?

Tags: запятые, обороты-с-как

В предложении «Топ-5 идей как интересно встретить Новый год» нужна ли запятая перед «как»? Склоняюсь, что нет. Типа топ-5 идей интересной встречи Нового года... Верно ли мое умозаключение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. С точки зрения грамматики  возможны определительные сочетания:  ***идея встретить Новый год, идея интересной встречи нового года.*** Но при наличии союза КАК мы можем использовать только **сложное предложение** с союзной связью.
2. Можно написать так: ***Топ-5 идей, как интересно встретить Новый год.*** Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным (не определительным), запятая ставится. Запись без запятой будет считаться грамматически **некорректной.**

Но такую конструкцию удобно использовать в тексте, например: У нас было пять идей, как интересно встретить Новый год.  Но у нас, вероятно,  заголовок, а не текст.

3. У Розенталя есть особая тема **для оформления заголовков**. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=168#pp168

Там есть вариант с двоеточием.

**Двоеточие** ставится в заголовках, распадающихся на две части с четким интонационным делением, отличающихся смысловой насыщенностью, предельной краткостью и нередко эмоциональной выразительностью. Первая часть называет общую проблему, место действия, лицо, а вторая — содержит конкретизацию названного в первой части.

Можно предложить следующее оформление: ***Топ-5 идей: как интересно встретить Новый год***

Answer (score 0):

Здесь придаточное определительное: *топ-5 идей* (каких?)**,** ***как встретить Новый год.*** Оснований не ставить запятую нет.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

- > У них было семь идей, как свою шарагу назвать: собор, сходняк,
  > советский союз, фронда, ложа, вече и профсоюзы.
- > ― Есть хорошая идея, как тебе избежать отставки…

Запятая перед *как* не ставится [в пяти случаях](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183); ни один из с вашим не совпадает.